# Объединение 2 результатов SQL запросов из разных БД

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

Есть 2 БД (Oracle и PostgreSQL) из которых отдельными запросами вытягиваются данные. Можно ли как-то эти данные объединить в один массив данных? Я смотрел в сторону SQLAlchemy, но с инструментом пока не знаком и не уверен, поможет ли он в решении задачи.

Comment: Наверняка возможно. Excel точно сможет :) Какими инструментами вы вытаскиваете данные, где их сохраняете и как хотите объеденить(в чем) и, собственно, а что дальше? Получили 2 набора данных, объеденили и куда это все девать?

Comment: Вытаскиваю в IDE обычными SQL запросами. Дальше либо работа с ними в той же IDE с pandas/matplotlib, либо импорт в Excel. Да, я могу  выгрузить 2 таблицы по отдельности, но эксель не переварит такой объем.

Comment: Как вариант экспортировать их в sql файлы в виде инструкций, там и объединять, импорт должен справиться

Comment: https://dbeaver.io/ вместо IDE будет более полезен

Comment: Чисто теоретически - если нужен объединённый набор, и это постоянно, то вполне разумно одну СУБД сделать базовой и инструктировать её на получение нужных данных от второй СУБД и возврат одного объединённого набора. По крайней мере Постгресс через внешний враппер данные с Оракла брать точно умеет.

Comment: прокиньте дб-линк из одной БД в другую и выкачайте всё одним запросом

Comment: Проблема в том, что речь про корпоративные системы, а у меня нет соответствующих прав на изменение конфигурации/создание новых таблиц. Только чтение. А речь, по сути, про ad-hoc аналитику.
По поводу "сделать одну СУБД базовой" (тем более, что в Postgre данные давно не обновляются, т.к. мастер система переехала на Oracle) - этот вопрос давно поднимался, но тогда инженеры посчитали, что это слишком трудозатратно мапить данные из 2 систем и сливать всё в одну БД.

Comment: `Postgre данные давно не обновляются, т.к. мастер система переехала на Oracle` - ну хоть где-то есть разумные люди!  я наблюдаю только случаи, когда ИТ-балбесики (сидящие в начальстве) пытаются выполнить обратное перемещение - заменить нескрепный оракл на бесплатный посгрес (попытки, ясно дело, неудачные, даже для серверов отчётности, где OLTP нет)